# Managed Package - View Components - View Dependencies

Tags: managed-package, administration, timeout, upgrade, alternatives

Trying to figure out how I'm going to **track what changes** in each installation of a **managed package in Salesforce** (in this case, **Rootstock**, but also possibly **Financial Force**).  Not necessarily Apex changes (though an effective way of seeing that would be great), but objects added/removed, dependencies, etc.

I'm not going to rely upon, or trust, any list maintained by a human at the Managed Package provider's company.

So my plan is to do it in Excel.  Simply grab a dump of the "View Components" and "View Dependencies" screens and store them in an ongoing spreadsheet with some simple formulas/routines to compare.

**Problem I ran into is**:   I can't even **load** the *View Components/Dependencies* screen (so far..) in either sandbox OR Production.  Waited 15 minutes in Sandbox (telling Chrome constantly to "wait" for it to respond).  Waited 10 minutes so far in Production.

Any thoughts on how to obtain this same listing?  Thanks!

Bad...

[image: Bad]

...worse.

[image: Worse - timeout]

---

Example of good output for reference.

[image: Good result]

---

**UPDATE**:   45 minutes, still waiting...
[image: 45 minutes later]

Comment: You mentioned FF, common issue when that is installed. Even trying to create a VF page causes timeout. Takes several attempts and a lot of waiting but it will eventually load....

Comment: Hah.    I'll bet you haven't met Rootstock.  Ugh.  Sweet mercy...     Over 540 custom objects.  Either 14k or 17k fields therein according to SF support on a case we have open.   No clue how many lines of code (would be morbidly interested in knownig).  "Only" 82 tabs (ahem).  Visualforce EVERYWHERE (so no benefit of standard views, mixed bag there).   I keep retelling myself to appreciate what it DOES DO and was purchased FOR........  I need a mantra......

Comment: But the package doesn't count against my org limits, so that makes it all better.      (that's called Sarcasm, folks)   :-)

Comment: Haha, I am glad I am not is supply chain management or accounting. It is amazing to me that cloud solutions like this exist when most companies have such specific requirements. Impressive actually....BUT it does take a performance hit. I would hate to be the first person in the AM to "Warm up" the org. good gawd....

Comment: Have you tried re-compiling all classes to see if that makes a difference?

Comment: Yes, recompiled (a new concept to me after 6+ years for managed packages, just recently learned this).  It's just tooooo big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a tool that get's your org's metadata through the metadata API.

For example if you use eclipse, go to the root of your project, there is a folder that is named "Referenced Packages" open it and there you see all packages installed with their components.

Now - if you use a version control system on your project like git, you can easily track changes to all folders and files with it.

You can use also other tools like ant [Force.com Migration Tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_Migration_Tool) or other IDEs.

Another choice is to buy a third party tool like [OwnBackup](https://www.ownbackup.com/products/backup-for-salesforce) for backing up your org's data and metadata, there you can easily compare versions of metadata backups

I Use this backup tool so I can recommend it, it is easy to use, but it cost money...

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the options..!   Not wanting to be in the dev world any deeper than necessary, Git is not what I'd want, but you have several ideas that bear investigation.   Thanks again.

Comment: Metadata tools FROM WITHIN SF do not work either.  Eclipse ends up being the "obvious" (sigh) choice.  Unfortunately.   Thanks.  ;)

Comment: I use today [Illuminated Cloud](http://www.illuminatedcloud.com/). this is the best tool for any development mission. cost a little but does great work!!!